# Combining and eliminating keys value pairs in array

Tags: php, arrays, unique

A PHP question about arrays. Suppose we have two arrays:

```
[first] => Array
    (
        [0] => users
        [1] => posts
        [2] => comments
    )

[second] => Array
    (
        [users] => the_users
        [posts] => the_posts
        [comments] => the_comments
        [options] => the_options
    )
```

How can I compare these two arrays? Meaning, how can we check whether or not the value in the first array is equal to the key in the second array (array_flip?) after combining them somehow (array_merge?). And whichever value/key pair matches, remove them from the array.

Basically, the end result would be the two arrays combined, duplicates removed, and the only index will be:

```
[third] => Array
    (
        [options] => the_options
    )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
$third = array_diff_key($second,array_flip($first));
```

Comment: Ahhhhh ! array_diff_key is exactly what I wanted. Thanks so much Vik.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a built-in function for this, but if there isn't, try:

```
$third = array();
foreach(array_keys($second) as $item)
  if(!in_array($item, $first))
    $third[$item] = $second[$item];
```

Note that this assumes that `$first` will not have an item that doesn't have a corresponding key in `$second`. To account for this, you could have an additional loop (I don't know what you would set the value in `$third` to for these, maybe `null`:

```
foreach($first as $item)
  if(!in_array($item, array_keys($second)))
    $third[$item] = null;
```

Comment: Yeah, was going to ask if there was a built in function as well. I had done something very similar to your second foreach, which works just fine. Was wondering if there was another way of doing it, but thanks dude :)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the edit. The second foreach you just added is unnecessary for what I want to do currently - however, will be useful in the future no doubt.

Comment: This is at best O(n^k) or O(n^2), depending on your 2 answers, which is awful when you could be doing it in O(n) time.  Equivalent of counting to 1,000,000 when you could just count to 1000.

Comment: @evan, well, yeah. I agree. On a small scale, such as this one, the actual execution time will be negligible, probably a few microseconds. For thousands and thousands of array items, the run time difference between this solution and your solution could be noticeable. Caveat emptor.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple to do and this way is extremely efficient:

```
$third = $second;

foreach($first as $value)
{
    if (isset($third[$value]))
    {
      unset($third[$value]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the answer to ur question

```
$first= array
(
    "0" => "users",
    "1" => "posts",
    "2" => "comments"
);
$firstf=array_flip($first);
$second = array
(
    "users" => "the_users",
    "posts" => "the_posts",
    "comments" => "the_comments",
    "options" => "the_options"
);
$third=array_diff_key($second,$firstf);
print_r($third);
```